# R Shiny read different tables based on drop down menu for table output

Tags: r, shiny

I have two dropdown menus on my app. Depending on the input of one of the dropdown menus, I want a different table to be read. When the user clicks the action button, I want to display the table's reading of the appropriate row based on the dropdown menu options.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

# Import the tables
Ans_yes <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\...\\IfYes.csv")
Ans_no <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\...\\IfNo.csv")

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Title Here"),
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Generator",
            mainPanel(
            selectInput("Number", "Number",
                c("1",
                  "2",
                  "3",
                  "4"),
                
        selectInput("Option1", "Option", 
                    c("Yes", "No")),
        
        actionButton("Enter", "Enter"))),
        
        )
    ))

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

    NumClick <- reactive({
        input$Number
    })
    
    OptClick <- reactive({
        input$Option1
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$Enter, 
                 {req(input$Option1);
                 req(input$Number)}
                 )
    
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Create a reactive value to store your data in using `reactiveVal` then use `observeEvent()` with `eventExpr` being your action button to write your preloaded data to the reactive value.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to store any variable that might change because of a user's input inside either a `reactiveVal()` or a `reactiveValues()`. This allows you to use functions such as `observeEvent()` to listen to user inputs then update the variables content based off whatever logic you want.

In the example below I've slightly edited your code to have a reactive Value called `data_choice()` that changes based of `input$Option1`. I've also added a table output so you can see the internal variable has changed when the user presses the button.

```
library(shiny)

# Import the tables
Ans_yes <- head(iris,5)
Ans_no <- head(iris,10)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel("Title Here"),
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
    "Generator",
    mainPanel(
      selectInput("Number", "Number",
                  c("1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"),
                  multiple = FALSE),
      
      selectInput("Option1", "Option",
                  c("Yes", "No"),
                  multiple = FALSE),
      
      actionButton("Enter", "Enter"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )))

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  data_choice <- reactiveVal(Ans_yes)
  
  observeEvent(input$Enter,{
               
               if (input$Option1 == "Yes") {
                 data_choice(Ans_yes)
               } else{
                 data_choice(Ans_no)
               }
               print(data_choice())})
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data_choice()
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```